# Paso de parametros a Procecimientos Almacendao Array SqlServer C#

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado

```
procedure [dbo].[sp.MtoProcedimiento.Listar2]

 @ListEjercicios as nvarchar(255),
 @ListProcedimientos as VARCHAR(MAX)=null,   
 @ListTipoEventos as VARCHAR(MAX)=null,
 @ListTipoCaracteres as VARCHAR(MAX)=null,
 @ListTipoCompras as VARCHAR(MAX)=null,
 @Descripcion as Varchar(Max)=null,
 @Mensaje as varchar(Max)=null output
AS
 BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

     
 SET @Query=N'select 
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId,
 MtoCompania.DescripcionCorta,
 MtoProcedimiento.Ejercicio,
 MtoProcedimiento.NoLicitacion,
 MtoProcedimiento.Descripcion,
 MtoEstado.MtoEstadoId,
 MtoEstado. Descripcion [Status],
 VistaProcedimientosIMS.numeroIM,
 MtoProcedimiento.CompraCovid [CompraCovid],
 ''Art.'' + MtoArticulo.Descripcion + '' Fracc. '' +  
 DetalleArticulo.Descripcion as Fundamento,
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoEventoId,
 MtoTipoEvento.DescripcionCorta [TipoEvento],
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoCompraId,
 MtoTipoCompra.Descripcion [TipoCompra],
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoCaracterId,
 MtoCaracter.DescripcionCorta [TipoCaracter],
 (select Count(MtoContratoId) from MtoContrato where    
 MtoContrato.EstadoContrato<>4 and 
 MtoContrato.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoprocedimientoId) as 
 NumContratos,
 (select sum(CantOrig * PrecioNeto) from VistaContratos
group by MtoProcedimientoId
having VistaContratos.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId) as MontoOriginal,
VistaObtenerProveedoresPorProcedimiento.Proveedores,
 MtoProcedimiento.Comite,
 MtoProcedimiento.SubComite,
 MtoProcedimiento.Caso,
 MtoProcedimiento.NumeroSesion,
 MtoProcedimiento.FechaSesion,
 MtoProcedimiento.Observaciones
 from MtoProcedimiento
 left join MtoTipoCompra on    
 MtoTipoCompra.MtoTipoCompraId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoCompraId
 left join MtoEstado on  
 MtoEstado.MtoEstadoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoEstadoId
 LEFT join VistaProcedimientosIMS ON 
      VistaProcedimientosIMS.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId
  left join MtoArticulo on   
  MtoArticulo.MtoArticuloId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoArticuloId
  left join DetalleArticulo on 
  DetalleArticulo.DetalleArticuloId=MtoProcedimiento.DetalleArticuloId
  left join MtoCompania on 
  MtoCompania.MtoCompaniaId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoCompaniaId
  left join MtoTipoEvento on 
  MtoTipoEvento.MtoTipoEventoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoEventoId
  left join MtoCaracter on 
  MtoCaracter.MtoCaracterId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoCaracterId
  left join VistaObtenerProveedoresPorProcedimiento on 
  VistaObtenerProveedoresPorProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId
  where MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId>0 
  ';
    
 
 IF @ListProcedimientos IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN 
   
   SET @Query= @Query + ' AND MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId in (' + @ListProcedimientos +')'    
  END 

   IF @ListTipoEventos IS NOT NULL 
     BEGIN 
        SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoTipoEvento.MtoTipoEventoId in ('  
        + @ListTipoEventos +')'
     END 


 IF @ListTipoCaracteres IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoCaracter.MtoCaracterId  in (' + @ListTipoCaracteres +')'  
  END 

 IF @ListTipoCompras IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoTipoCompra.MtoTipoCompraId  in (' + @ListTipoCompras +')' 
  END
   
     IF @Descripcion IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN       
       set @Query=@Query + ' AND MtoProcedimiento.Descripcion Like ''%'+ (@Descripcion) + '%'' '
      END

  IF @ListEjercicios IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN        
           
   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoProcedimiento.Ejercicio in ('
   SET @Query =@Query + 'select cast(value as int)  as value from dbo.SplitString('+ @ListEjercicios + ','','')'
   SET @Query= @Query + ')'



 END    

 set @Query= @Query + ' order by Ejercicio desc'
    
 set @Mensaje = @Query

 print @Query

 EXECUTE sp_executesql  @Query 

 select * from MtoProcedimiento
 where Ejercicio in
    (iif(@ListEjercicios = 0, 0, (select cast(value as int) as value from dbo.SplitString(@ListEjercicios,','))))


 set @query=N'select * from MtoProcedimiento'

 if @ListEjercicios > 0
    begin
        SET @query = @query+ 'where Ejercicio in (select cast(value as int)  as value from dbo.SplitString(@ListEjercicios,'',''))'         
    end
 

EXEC sp_Executesql   @query             

 END
```

ahora bien lo que necesito recibir es un array de valores para hacer una consulta tipo in

para lo cual uso el siguiente código de C#

```
 public ActionResult ListarProcedimientos(int[] itemEjercicios, int[] itemLicitaciones, int[] itemTipoEventos, int[] itemTipoCaracter, int?[] itemTipoCompras, string Descripcion)
    {
        var Mensaje = string.Empty;

        var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        
        var connectionStringsql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringsql);

        Response oResponse = new Response();
        
        //var ejercicio = Ejercicio != null ? Ejercicio : 0;

       var resultListEjercicios = itemEjercicios != null ? string.Join(",", itemEjercicios) : (object)DBNull.Value;
       var resultListLicitaciones = itemLicitaciones != null ? string.Join(",", itemLicitaciones) : (object)DBNull.Value;
       var resultListItemEventos = itemTipoEventos != null ? string.Join(",", itemTipoEventos) : (object)DBNull.Value;
       var ResultListCaracter = itemTipoCaracter != null ? string.Join(",", itemTipoCaracter) : (object)DBNull.Value;
       var ResultListTipoCompra = itemTipoCompras != null ? string.Join(",", itemTipoCompras) : (object)DBNull.Value;

        var ids = itemEjercicios !=null ?  String.Join(",", itemEjercicios.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray()) : (object)DBNull.Value;


        List<MtoProcedimientoListarMV> oLista = new List<MtoProcedimientoListarMV>();            

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[sp.MtoProcedimiento.Listar2]"))
            {

                try
                {
                    //SqlDataAdapter adapter;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //resultListEjercicios = resultListEjercicios.Replace('""','''');
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListEjercicios", ids);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListProcedimientos", resultListLicitaciones);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListTipoEventos", resultListItemEventos);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListTipoCaracteres", ResultListCaracter);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListTipoCompras", ResultListTipoCompra);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", Descripcion);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    connection.Open();                       

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    Mensaje = cmd.Parameters["Mensaje"].Value.ToString();

                    connection.Close();

                    Session["SessionListarProcedimientos"] = dt;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        oLista.Add(
                            new MtoProcedimientoListarMV()
                            {
                               MtoProcedimientoId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MtoProcedimientoId"].ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["MtoProcedimientoId"].ToString()) : 0),
                               Ejercicio = dr["Ejercicio"].ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ejercicio"].ToString()) : 0,
                               Nolicitacion = dr["Nolicitacion"].ToString(),
                               Descripcion = dr["Descripcion"].ToString(),                                                             
                               oMtoEstado = new MtoEstado() { 
                                   MtoEstadoId= Convert.ToInt32(dr["MtoEstadoId"].ToString()),
                                   Descripcion = dr["Status"].ToString()
                               },
                            }
                        );                         
                    }
                    
                    return Json(new { data = oLista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    oResponse.succeeded = false;
                    oResponse.Message = "Error:" + ex.Message + " en la Linea: " + ex.StackTrace;
                    return Json(oResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);

                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            oResponse.succeeded = false;
            oResponse.Message = raise.Message;
            return Json(oResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }           
    }
```

cuando veo el parámetro que envió se envia correctamente sin embargo en la consulta me muestra el siguiente mensaje.

```
Message = "Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar '2022,2020,2019' al tipo de datos int."
```

estoy usando sqlserver 2012 por lo que implemente la función para [SplitString]

```
create function [dbo].[SplitString](
  @FullString nvarchar(max)
 ,@Separator nvarchar(1))
 returns @t Table(Value nvarchar(max))
 as
   begin

    declare @SingleString nvarchar(max)
    declare @SeparatorPosition  int = CHARINDEX(@Separator,@FullString)

while @SeparatorPosition>0      
    
    begin 
     set @SingleString =LEFT(@FullString,@SeparatorPosition-1)
     insert into @t  values (@SingleString)
     set @FullString =SUBSTRING(@FullString,@SeparatorPosition + 1, len(@FullString))
     set @SeparatorPosition= CHARINDEX(@Separator,@FullString)
    end

insert into @t values (@FullString)
```

Comment: Porque tratas de castear la lista de valores? no es simplemente, in tu variable? porque tratas de hacer un split? creo que tu problema es tu procedimiento...

Comment: bueno el int solo fue para que me arrojara la lista podría cambiar esa palabra por value, y me sigue mostrando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que a la funcion **SplitString** no le estas pasando el separador como segundo parametro. Fijate que en mensaje de error:

```
"Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar '2022,2020,2019' al tipo de datos int."
```

El valor que le estas pasando esta separados por "**,**" ('2022,2020,2019') por lo cual en la consulta, esa funcion deberias llamarla asi:

```
...value from dbo.SplitString(@ListEjercicios,','))
```

Otra cuestion que seria mejorable, es en el sp no tenes una necesidad concreta de hacer sp_Executesql. Esto es costoso y poco performante y por la logica descripta se podria resolver con un query:

```
SELECT * FROM MtoProcedimiento
WHERE Ejercicio IN (SELECT CAST([value] as int) FROM dbo.SplitString(@ListEjercicios,','))
OR @ListEjercicios IS NULL
```

Saludos!!

Comment: que tal agradezco la atención la cuestión de usar sp_Executesql es debido a que la consulta no esta completa solo puse un ejemplo, ya que el procedimiento como verán recibe mas parámetros que se tienen que aplicar al filtro de búsqueda. modifico el sp y dejo el completo

Comment: @HoracioXochitemol tu edición fue rechazada ya que debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien inserte el código. En todo caso, redacta tu propia respuesta. No olvides además [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Comment: actualice el procedimiento para ver porque uso sp_Executesql, ahora bien si hay forma de genrar toda la consulta sin que pueda usar executesql, podrian echarme una mano apra mejorarla